# Implementing a basic predator-prey simulation

Tags: c, algorithm, simulation

I am trying to implement a predator-prey simulation, but I am running into a problem.
A predator searches for nearby prey, and eats it. If there are no near by prey, they move to a random vacant cell.
Basically the part I am having trouble with is when I advanced a "generation."
Say I have a grid that is 3x3, with each cell numbered from 0 to 8.
If I have 2 predators in 0 and 1, first predator 0 is checked, it moves to either cell 3 or 4
For example, if it goes to cell 3, then it goes on to check predator 1. This may seem correct
but it kind of "gives priority" to the organisms with lower index values.. I've tried using 2 arrays, but that doesn't seem to work either as it would check places where organisms are but aren't. ._.
Anyone have an idea of how to do this "fairly" and "correctly?"

Comment: If you're worried about giving an unfair advantage to predators in the lower indexes because of your update loop's scanning ... why not simply start the scan from a random location each time?  Pick a random point on the grid, scan from there until you've wrapped around back to that point.  Next time you'll start from a different point.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the most logical and simplest answer. Hm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently did a similar task in Java. Processing the predators starting from the top row to bottom not only gives "unfair advantage" to lower indices but also creates patterns in the movement of the both preys and predators.

I overcame this problem by choosing both row and columns in random ordered fashion. This way, every predator/prey has the same chance of being processed at early stages of a generation.

A way to randomize would be creating a linked list of `(row,column)` pairs. Then shuffle the linked list. At each generation, choose a random index to start from and keep processing.

Answer (score 2):

More as a comment then anything else if your prey are so dense that this is a common problem I suspect you don't have a "population" that will live long.  Also as a comment update your predators randomly.  That is, instead of stepping through your array of locations take your list of predators and randomize them and then update them one by one.  I think is necessary but I don't know if it is sufficient.

Comment: Good biological observation, but I'm afraid it's not technically sufficient, as you will still risk that the randomization will pick two adjacent predators and update them incorrectly - see my answer.

Comment: Oops - I didn't read the question thoroughly enough; you are right that randomization is necessary. Whether it is also sufficient depends on the rules; if the rules he's shown us are the only one, I think randomization is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved with a technique called *double buffering*, which is also used in computer graphics (in order to prevent the image currently being drawn from disturbing the image currently being displayed on the screen). Use *two* arrays. The first one holds the current state, and you make all *decisions* about movement based on the first array, but you *perform* the movement in the other array. Then, you swap their roles.

Edit: Looks like I didn't read your question thoroughly enough. Double buffering and randomization might both be needed, depending on how complex your rules are (but if there are no rules other than the ones you've described, randomization should suffice). They solve two distinct problems, though:

- Double buffering solves the problem of *correctness* when you have rules where decisions about what will happen to a creature in a cell depends on the contents of neighbouring cells, and the decisions about neighbouring cells also depend on this cell. If you e.g. have a rule that says that if two predators are adjacent, they will *both* move away from each other, you need double buffering. Otherwise, after you've moved the first predator, the second one won't see any adjacent predator and will remain in place.
- Randomization solves the problem of *fairness* when there are limited resources, such as when a prey only can be eaten by one predator (which seems to be the problem that concerned you).

Comment: Double-buffering will also introduce a problem where two predators might move into the same cell, or eat the same prey. Can be solved by checking both buffers, I guess.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: True; there is actually a need to make decisions based on _both_ buffers; that didn't occur to me before. +1.

Answer (score 0):

How about some sort of round robin method. Put your predators in a circular linked list and keep a pointer to the node that's currently "first". Then, advance that first pointer to the next place in the list each generation. You could insert new predators either at the front or the back of your circular list with ease.

Comment: This still introduces an undesirably regular pattern into the algorithm, throwing a wrench into the kind of simultaneity that the simulation is seeking.  Imagine the effect on a large data set.

Comment: With a large number of predators the regularity would be more noticeable, but I thought the focus was on fairness, not randomization. If your goal is randomization, you could advance the pointer by a random amount each time, or keep it stationary and read through the list x nodes at a time where x and the number of predators are relatively prime.